# React Native - Data is not loaded in the screen but if reload the page I am able to see the data

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I am new to React Native.
I am storing the some data like GUID, userID, company name , in AsyncStorage when user login to the apps for the first time. I want to load the department details in department page based on selected company  name which tag to unique GUID.

I am able to get the data from the AsyncStorage. Now I need to pass the GUID to "setDepartment(GUID)" store then pass to fetch API to get the data from server.

Problem : The data not able to load open when I open the department page but if I refresh the page , I am able to see the data in the screen. I am not sure where I make the mistakes. I think it something do with useEffect and useCallback. Please Guide Me. Thank You.

```
 const DepartmentScreen = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const departments = useSelector((state) => state.departments.allDepartment);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [GUID, setGUID] = useState("");

  const getData = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem("companyData").then((companyData) => {
        let parsed = JSON.parse(companyData);
        setGUID(parsed.GUID);
        console.log(GUID);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [dispatch, getData]);

  const loadDepartment = useCallback(async () => {
    setError(null);
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      //getData();
      await dispatch(departmentAction.setDepartment(GUID));
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [dispatch, setIsLoading, setError]);

  useEffect(() => {
    loadDepartment();
  }, [dispatch, loadDepartment]);

  if (error) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>
          AN ERROR OCCURRED {error} + {GUID}
        </Text>
        <Button title="Reload" onPress={loadDepartment} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  if (!isLoading && departments.length === 0) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>NO DEPARTMENT FOUND</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={styles.ButtonView}>
        <View>
          <Button title="Listed" />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button title="De-Listed" />
        </View>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={departments}
        renderItem={(itemData) => (
          <DepartmentItem
            name={itemData.item.deptName}
            code={itemData.item.deptCode}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I have found the  solution for this issue. This issue mainly cause by the State management. It is not update properly. So instead get the state from the department screen and pass to Store-Action, I directly get my state in the Store-Action page by using the getState when I dispatch the fetch function. 

 return async (dispatch, getState) => {//functions here}